# How to change the mysql root password

Tags: mysql, linux, passwords, redhat

I have installed MySQL server 5 on redhat linux.  I can't login as root so I can't change the root password.

```
mysql -u root -p  
Enter password:  <blank>
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
(using password: NO)
```

When I try to set one like this:

```
mysqladmin -u root password 'newpass'
```

I get an error:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' 
(using password: NO)'
```

As if there is a root password set.

I have also tried resetting the password using (described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-generic))

```
/sbin/service mysqld start --skip-grant-tables
```

And then making:

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpass')     
->  WHERE User='root';  
ERROR 1142 (42000): UPDATE command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'user'
```

I even uninstalled mysql-server (using yum) and then reinstalled it but that did not help.

How do I force reset the root password?

Comment: Check that your mysqld is installed, enabled, and on with command: `sudo service mysqld status`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed the MySQL installation and deleted the data files, and then reinstalled it.

Then I was able to set the root password.  Once you set the root password to something. mysqladmin won't let you reset it if you don't know it.

To reset it, you've got to have ownership over how mysqld is executed, and feed it an init file to change the root password:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 12):

One option is to save `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpass') WHERE User='root';` into a file and then manually start `mysqld` with `--init-file=FILENAME`. Once the server starts, it should reset your password, and then you should be able to log in. After this, you should shut down the server and start it normally.

Comment: Good lord, why would someone give a -1 to the only solution I found to be working. An init sql file was the only way I could overwrite the mysql root user password and be able to use it. It is a shame you need to fallback to such operations on a freshly installed software, yet it is good to have a **reliable** workaround.

Comment: `sudo mysql service stop && echo "UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpass') WHERE User='root';" >  /tmp/reset.sql && sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start --init-file=/tmp/reset.sql`

Answer (score 10):

A little late to the game, but I had the same issue on a raspberry pi install and found out that it needs elevation. Adding a sudo to the front of the password change allowed it to work.

```
sudo mysqladmin -u root password 'newpass'
```

followed by an elevated sql access

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

If either are not run as sudo, it will fail.

Comment: Although I'm not using `mysqladmin`, the `sudo mysql -u root -p` worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

The root user password is an empty string by default.

And `(using password: NO)` says that there is no password.

Do you try to login from another system? I imagine you can only login as root user locally.

Comment: do i neet to be root of the system in order to be root in the mysql server ?

Comment: I am not sure, but I don't think so. Unfortunately I never used redhat... EDIT: But why don't you just try it?

Comment: Note that if you want to try logging in with no password, you should just avoid specifying `-p` on the command line altogether.

Comment: Note: The root password may not by blank by default, now (just found this out).  I installed MySQL 5.7.16 from a yum repository and found that the installer had created a temporary password that was stored in a plain text file :P (for yum this was /var/log/mysqld.log)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the -p from your command. -p forces the prompt for password.

Use :
`mysql -u root`

This will resolve your problem.

Comment: This only works if there is no root password. If a root password has been set, it must be provided.

Answer (score 2):

This helped me on Windows with MySQL Server 5.6. Make sure you change the `mysqld` path to point to where you have installed MySql Server, for me it was `"C:\Program Files\mysql\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe"`:

1. Log on to your system as Administrator.
2. Stop the MySQL server if it is running. For a server that is 
   running as a Windows service, go to the Services manager: 
   From the Start menu, select Control Panel, then 
   Administrative Tools, then Services. Find the MySQL 
   service in the list and stop it.

   If your server is not running as a service, you may need to use 
   the Task Manager to force it to stop.
3. Create a text file containing the following statements. 
   Replace the password with the password that you want to use.

   ```
   UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```

   Write the UPDATE and FLUSH statements each on a single line. The UPDATE statement resets the password for all root accounts, and the FLUSH statement tells the server to reload the grant tables into memory so that it notices the password change.
4. Save the file. For this example, the file will be named `C:\mysql-init.txt`.
5. Open a console window to get to the command prompt: From the Start menu, select Run, then enter cmd as the command to be run.
6. Start the MySQL server with the special --init-file option (notice that the backslash in the option value is doubled):

   ```
   C:\> C:\mysql\bin\mysqld --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
   ```

   If you installed MySQL to a location other than C:\mysql, adjust the command accordingly.

   The server executes the contents of the file named by the --init-file option at startup, changing each root account password.

   You can also add the --console option to the command if you want server output to appear in the console window rather than in a log file.

   If you installed MySQL using the MySQL Installation Wizard, you may need to specify a --defaults-file option:

   ```
   C:\> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld.exe"
        --defaults-file="C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.5\\my.ini"
        --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
   ```

   The appropriate --defaults-file setting can be found using the Services Manager: From the Start menu, select Control Panel, then Administrative Tools, then Services. Find the MySQL service in the list, right-click it, and choose the Properties option. The Path to executable field contains the --defaults-file setting.
7. After the server has started successfully, delete C:\mysql-init.txt.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 2):

Probably a bit late here , but here is what I did :

create file resetpass.sh which has :

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpassword') WHERE User='root';

# mysqld_safe --init-file=resetpass.sh

# service mysqld start --skip-grant-tables

# mysql -u root -p
```

Enter pass

```
mysql >  change root pass ; flush privs;
```

quit

```
# restart mysql service
```

The MySQL version I was using was 5.1.73 under centos6

Answer (score 1):

Try do this:

```
mysql -u root
```

and then:

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass')
    ->                   WHERE User='root'; 

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Worked fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, in MySQL 5.7 the temp password gets put in `/var/log/mysqld`, but this is evidently not the case in 5.6.

With MySQL version 5.6 installed on RHEL 6.7, I finally found the temporary root password set during install was placed in the file `/root/.mysql_secret`.

Answer (score 0):

open mysql

now enter the following commands :

```
use mysql;

update user set PASSWORD=password("updated password")  where User='root';

flush privileges;
```