# mysql uroot password in UBUNTU

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, passwords

I get this error "access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password no)" to which i've found a temporary solution to. I do in the terminal:

1. sudo service mysql stop (Enter my password)
2. (Then I navigate to usr/bin) and type:
   sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
3. (Open a new Terminal and type): 
   mysql 
   use mysql;
   UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD('I_enter_my_new)password') WHERE user= 'root';
   exit
   sudo service mysql start (then I enter my password)

This works fine only until I shut down my pc and log back in again . I would like a permanent solution to this please if anyone has one.

Comment: What do you actually type that gives you that error?  Did you do `$ mysql -uroot` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing all the --skip-grant-tables jazz, hop into mysql and do that:

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'root' identified by 'newpassword' with grant option;
flush privileges;
quit;
```

Then you can restart the service and try logging in with mysql -uroot -p and enter the new password.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned at

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8789560/631619

> The root user password is an empty string by default.
>
> And (using password: NO) says that there is no password.

Did you try `$ mysql -uroot` ?

Also, I'm not sure if you should be stop and starting with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing: a command like

`grant all privileges on *.* to 'root' identified by 'newpassword' with grant option;`

will remain in the history, who knows for how long. Be careful in production, do not put 'newpassword' in cleartext but in the hashed form, or disable history:

`export MYSQL_HISTFILE=/dev/null && mysql -u root`