# What is the default root pasword for MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, linux, passwords, password-recovery, mysql-5.7

Cannot login to MySQL database after fresh install with root ID and empty/no password like other older MySQL versions do.

Comment: root no longer has  one because it does not use one.  By default the auth method is auth socket. use sudo to access with root access, change the auth method to password and set a password if you need a root lmysql oogin without root system access.

Comment: @G.Martin would you mind expanding this comment into an answer with more detailed steps?  I think this is the solution I want to use but don't know how to change the auth method.  (`sudo mysql -u root` does work for me - I want to change it so I can just do `mysql -u root` with no password)

Comment: Sorry You probably already figured this out but I found out my post only applies to debian distros.

If its still an issue (doubt it) I can provide more detail.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

After you installed MySQL-community-server 5.7 from fresh on linux, you will need to find the temporary password from /var/log/mysqld.log to login as root.

1. `grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log`
2. Run `mysql_secure_installation` to change new password

ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html

Comment: Thank you! Kind of crazy to find this information here instead of the MySQL 5.7 doc from Oracle.

Comment: This saves my life... been searching for solution everywhere and this solves all my problem. Even the document from mysql website didn't mention about this. This is crazy man. Thanks!

Comment: Where would you look on a Windows machine?

Comment: @rotaercz try following this guide? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: /var/log/mysqld.log does not exist for me (mariadb on mint)

Comment: thank you ! solved my problem here!! never knew about this "temporary password"!!

Comment: unbelievable I know I shouldn't add this kind of "me too!" comments but holy crap the official documentation would not even come up first for this information

Comment: It's not there.

Comment: In MySQL 5.6, you may find the password [in a hidden file in root's home directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47169395/5419599).

Comment: For those who can't find the `/var/log/mysqld.log`, just run `sudo mysql_secure_installation`. Remmember to run that command with `sudo` or you will get the "Access denied" error.

Comment: `sudo mysql_secure_installation` will do ABSOLUTELY NOTHING if the MySQL root account makes use of the "auth_socket" plugin. I elaborate in [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991228/what-is-the-default-root-pasword-for-mysql-5-7/57948037#57948037)

Answer (score 178):

There's so many answers out there saying to reinstall mysql or use some combo of

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

and / or

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password')
```

and / or something else ...

**... None of it was working for me**

---

**Here's what worked for me, on Ubuntu 18.04, from the top**

With special credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost#answer-42742610) for digging me out of the frustration on this ...

```
$ sudo apt install mysql-server
$ sudo cat /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

Note the lines which read:

```
user     = debian-sys-maint
password = blahblahblah
```

Then:

```
$ mysql -u debian-sys-maint -p
Enter password: // type 'blahblahblah', ie. password from debian.cnf

mysql> USE mysql
mysql> SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| User             | Host      | plugin                |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| root             | localhost | auth_socket           |
| mysql.session    | localhost | mysql_native_password |
| mysql.sys        | localhost | mysql_native_password |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost | mysql_native_password |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';
mysql> COMMIT;  // When you don't have auto-commit switched on
```

Either:

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

Or:

```
// For MySQL 5.7+
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('new_password') where user='root';
```

Then:

```
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> COMMIT;  // When you don't have auto-commit switched on
mysql> EXIT

$ sudo service mysql restart
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: // Yay! 'new_password' now works!
```

Comment: I've followed these steps and it doesn't work for me. Everything looks good, but as soon as I restart MySQL, the plugin value gets reset to `auth_socket`. Any idea what's missing?

Comment: @MattRaible I don't know to be honest. Perhaps check the answer I credited / linked above?

Comment: Didn't work for me initially. Then I tried issuing a COMMIT before EXIT and it worked!

Comment: @LeandroG  Good to know.  The above method relies on auto-commit being configured by default.

Comment: Worked for me but instead of using:
mysql -u debian-sys-maint -p ,
I had to use:
sudo mysql -u root .
When I used the first one the changes were not being saved even with COMMIT

Comment: Need to do a `commit;` before `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`.

Comment: After adding a `COMMIT;` after `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`, this did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Some have suggested adding `COMMIT` *before* `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`; some have suggested adding it *after*. I had `auto-commit` for my CLI, so I'm not sure where it should go, or if it matters. I've added it *after* in an edit.

Comment: Tested this. Mysql **5.7+** which is installed by default with **18.04 LTS** changes password with `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('new_password') where user='root';` so, you need to run that instead of `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';`

Comment: @message The code as posted (except for the comments) is **exactly** the code as used in real life. Please leave it alone!

Comment: @Stewart you can just reject my edit changes without that comment. Your solution didn't work for me completely.

Comment: @message, your workaround worked like a charm for me! Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much, after about an hour of trying this worked for me!

Comment: Not work for me, magic thing happens when I try `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your new password';` from https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/

Comment: I can confirm that on **5.7** this command `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';` doesn't work. You can see from the output as it says that 0 rows affected.
The one mentioned for **5.7+** does work as long as you don't forget to `Commit;` and `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`

Comment: MAN THANK YOU. I have been scratching my head to figure out whats wrong, following so many other steps, but this one is perfect

Comment: Everything was fine until I restarted and tried to login in the last step. I had to use the command like: sudo mysql -u root -p
Without sudo it was not working.

Comment: I cant believe connecting to a brand new mysql installation is so hard and not documented at all

Answer (score 36):

MySQL 5.7 changed the secure model: now MySQL root login requires a sudo

The simplest (and safest) solution will be create a new user and grant required privileges.

**1. Connect to mysql**

```
sudo mysql --user=root mysql
```

**2. Create a user for phpMyAdmin**

```
CREATE USER 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Reference - https://askubuntu.com/questions/763336/cannot-enter-phpmyadmin-as-root-mysql-5-7

Comment: To be honest I discarded this answer as pretty stupid at first and tried tons of other stuff including searching for random generated passwords in files which did not exist on my local Ubuntu Machine. However a simple SUDO and a blank password just did it. Have an upvote!

Answer (score 15):

MySQL server 5.7 was already installed by default on my new Linux Mint 19.

But, what's the MySQL `root` password? It turns out that:

**The default installation uses `auth_socket` for authentication, in lieu of passwords!**

It allows a password-free login, provided that one is logged into the Linux system with the same user name.  To login as the MySQL root `user`, one can use sudo:

```
sudo mysql --user=root
```

But how to then change the root password?  To illustrate what's going on,  I created a new user "me", with full privileges, with:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'me'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_new_password';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'me'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comparing "me" with "root":

```
mysql> SELECT user, plugin, HEX(authentication_string)  FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'me' or user = 'root';
+------+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| user | plugin                | HEX(authentication_string)                                                 |
+------+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| root | auth_socket           |                                                                            |
| me   | mysql_native_password | 2A393846353030304545453239394634323734333139354241344642413245373537313... |
+------+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Because it's using auth_socket, the root password cannot be changed: the `SET PASSWORD` command fails, and `mysql_secure_installation` desn't attain anything...

**==> To zap this alternate authentication mode and return the MySQL `root` user to using passwords:**

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'SOME_NEW_ROOT_PASSWORD';
```

A [good explanation.](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/)

More [details from the MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/socket-pluggable-authentication.html).

Answer (score 9):

In case you want to install mysql or percona unattended (like in my case ansible), you can use following script:

```bash
# first part opens mysql log
# second part greps lines with temporary password
# third part picks last line (most recent one)
# last part removes all the line except the password
# the result goes into password variable

password=$(cat /var/log/mysqld.log | grep "A temporary password is generated for" | tail -1 | sed -n 's/.*root@localhost: //p')

# setting new password, you can use $1 and run this script as a file and pass the argument through the script

newPassword="wh@teverYouLikE"

# resetting temporary password

mysql -uroot -p$password -Bse "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$newPassword';"
```

Comment: `cat: /var/log/mysqld.log: No such file or directory` I use ubuntu 18.04, and I installed it via tasksel. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: I would search for it: `find / -name mysqld 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 6):

It seems things were designed to avoid developers to set the root user, a better solution would be:

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

Then create a normal user, set a password, then use that user to work.

```
create user 'user'@'localhost' identified by 'user1234';
grant all on your_database.* to 'user'@'localhost';
select host, user from mysql.user;
```

Then try to access:

```
mysql -u user -p
```

Boom!

Comment: Nope. It was designed to set a password for root instead of empty password.

Comment: By default it is designed to connect only via local socket with root. Either way is a bad practice to use root to connect to MySQL even for dev, and my answer describes how to use a good practice of creating a non root user that actually works.

Answer (score 6):

MySQL 5.7 or newer generates a default temporary password after fresh install.

To use MySQL first you would be required to get that password from the log file which is present at the `/var/log/mysqld.log`. So follow the following process:

1. `grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log`
2. `mysql_secure_installation`

The second command is required to change the password for MySQL and also to make certain other changes like removing temporary databases, allow or disallow remote access to root user, delete anonymous users etc…

Answer (score 4):

None of these answers worked for me on Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 and MySQL 5.7.23. I spent a bunch of time trying and failing at setting the password and auth plugin manually, finding the password in logs (it's not there), etc.

The solution is actually super easy:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

It's really important to do this with `sudo`. If you try without elevation, you'll be asked for the root password, which you obviously don't have.

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of try, I could reset the default password with the following commands (Ubuntu and derivatives):

```
sudo -i
mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -uroot
use mysql;
update user set authentication_string=password('YOURPASSWORD') where user='root';
update user set plugin="mysql_native_password" where User='root';  
flush privileges;
quit;
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Sometimes, even after typed in the terminal

```
mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

I got the error that the mysqld don't exists. So, quit, and type the same commands again.

And the final command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Sometimes doesn't work. Only after restart the computer.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu Bionic 18.04 Mysql 5.7.29. Just thought I'd add the versions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed Linux Mint 19 (based on Ubuntu 18.04) on my machine. I installed MySQL 5.7 from the repo (*sudo apt install mysql-server*) and surprisingly during installation, the setup didn't prompt to enter *root* password. As a result I wasn't able to login into MySQL. I googled here and there and tried various answers I found on the net, including the accepted answer above. I uninstalled (purging all dpkgs with *mysql* in its name) and reinstalled again from the default Linux Mint repositories. NONE works.

After hours of unproductive works, I decided to reinstall MySQL from the official page. I opened MySQL download page (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt) for apt repo and clicked **Download** button at the bottom right.

Next, run it with dpkg:

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
```

At the installation setup, choose the MySQL version that you'd like to install. The default option is 8.0 but I changed it to 5.7. Click OK to quit. After this, you have a new MySQL repo in your Software Sources.

Update your repo:

```
sudo apt update
```

Finally, install MySQL:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

And now I was prompted to provide *root* password! Hope it helps for others with this same experience.

Comment: I spent days solving it while installing `mysql-server` from ubuntu repo but at the end official, the one MySQL provides, works.

Answer (score 1):

As of **Ubuntu 20.04 with MySql 8.0** : you can set the password that way:

1. login to mysql with `sudo mysql -u root`
2. change the password:

> ```
> USE mysql;
> UPDATE user set authentication_string=NULL where User='root';
> FLUSH privileges;
> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'My-N7w_And.5ecure-P@s5w0rd';
> FLUSH privileges;
> QUIT
> ```

now you should be able to login with `mysql -u root -p` (or to phpMyAdmin with username root) and your chosen password.

P,S:

You can also login with user `debian-sys-maint`, the password is written in the file `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`

Comment: Thank for sharing

Answer (score 1):

To do it in **non interactive mode (from a script):**

```
systemctl start mysqld
MYSQL_ROOT_TMP_PSW=$(grep 'temporary password' $logpath/mysqld.log |sed "s|.*: ||")

## POPULATE SCHEMAS WITH ROOT USER
/usr/bin/mysql --connect-expired-password -u root -p${MYSQL_ROOT_TMP_PSW} < "$mysql_init_script"
```

Here's the head of the init script

```
SET GLOBAL validate_password_policy=LOW;
FLUSH privileges;

SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('MYSQL_ROOT_PSW');
FLUSH privileges;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
FLUSH privileges;

...
```

Then restart the service `systemctl restart mysqld`

Answer (score 0):

I to was experiencing the same problem and the only thing I was able to do to make it work was to go this route:

```
drop user admin@localhost;
flush privileges;
create user admin@localhost identified by 'admins_password'
```

This allowed me to recreate my **username** and enter a **password** for the user name.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the data directory was automatically initialized with the `--initialize-insecure` option. So `/var/log/mysql/error.log` does not contain a temporary password but:

> [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please
>   consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.

What worked was:

```
shell> mysql -u root --skip-password
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

Details: [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual > 2.10.4 Securing the Initial MySQL Account](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/default-privileges.html)