# Default password of mysql in ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, passwords, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

I have installed ubuntu 16.04 server. Mysql server was installed by default in it. When I am trying to access the mysql with `mysql -u root -p`, I am unable to log in to mysql because I dont have the password. Is there any default password?

I have also tried with `--skip-grant-tables`, even this does not work. Even trying to log in with just `mysql -u root` is a failure.

Comment: Kindly approve the answer that resolves your query, so that it helps the community.

Comment: I just posted a new **WORKING** answer to this problem. None of the other advice was working for me on 18.04.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991228/what-is-the-default-root-pasword-for-mysql-5-7/50305285#50305285

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the default root pasword for MySQL 5.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991228/what-is-the-default-root-pasword-for-mysql-5-7)

Comment: @Debashisenator if you find my answer to be helpful, I'll appreciate if you accept my answer.. thanks!

Answer (score 159):

This is what you are looking for:
`sudo mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`
MySql on Debian-base Linux usually use a configuration file with the credentials.

Answer (score 142):

I had a fresh installation of `mysql-server` on Ubuntu 18.10 and couldn't login with default password. Then only I got to know that by default root user is authenticated using `auth_socket`. So as in the answer when the plugin changed to `mysql_native_password`, we can use mysql default password

```
$ sudo apt install mysql-server
$ sudo cat /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

You can find the following lines in there

```
user     = debian-sys-maint
password = password_for_the_user
```

Then:

```
$ mysql -u debian-sys-maint -p
Enter password:
```

type the password from debian.cnf

```
mysql> USE mysql
mysql> SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user;

+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| User             | Host      | plugin                |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| root             | localhost | auth_socket           |
| mysql.session    | localhost | mysql_native_password |
| mysql.sys        | localhost | mysql_native_password |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost | mysql_native_password |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';
mysql> COMMIT;
```

Either:

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password';
```

Or:

// For MySQL 5.7+

```
mysql>UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('new_password') where user='root';
```

**--Update--**

Sometimes you will need to restart your mysql server.

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

or

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

Comment: You should add some details as to what OP was doing wrong, and why this solution works

Comment: You should add that context as an edit to your answer :)

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 71):

Mysql by default has root user's authentication plugin as `auth_socket`, which requires the system user name and db user name to be the same.

Specifically, log in as root or `sudo -i` and just type `mysql` and you will be logged in as mysql `root`, you can then create other operating users.

If you do not have a root on host, I guess you should not be allowed to login to mysql as root?

Answer (score 37):

Although this is an old question, there are several of us still struggle to find an answer. At least I did. **Please don't follow all the lengthy solutions**. You could simply login to your mysql as root without providing any password (provided it is a fresh installation or you haven't changed the password since your installation) by adding sudo before your mysql command.
`$sudo mysql -uroot -p
mysql>`

This is because mysql changed the security model in one of the latest versions.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 23):

> Note that in Ubuntu systems running MySQL 5.7 (and later versions), the root MySQL user is set to authenticate using the auth_socket plugin by default rather than with a password. you will need to switch its authentication method from auth_socket to mysql_native_password

as @BeNiza said, they changed the security model. I did following steps and it works for mysql 5.7.27 on ubuntu 18.04

`sudo apt install mysql-server`

The MySQL database software is now installed, but its configuration is not yet complete.

To secure the installation, MySQL comes with a script that will ask whether we want to modify some insecure defaults. Initiate the script by typing:

`sudo mysql_secure_installation`

you should press <kbd>Y</kbd> and hit the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key at each prompt.

> This will cause issues if you use a weak password

You can simply login to your mysql as root without providing any password by adding sudo before your mysql command.

`sudo mysql`

`mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your-password';`

If you set a weak password you would see the following error:

> ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements

`mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

`mysql> exit`

> Note: After configuring your root MySQL user to authenticate with a password, you’ll no longer be able to access MySQL with the sudo mysql command used previously. Instead, you must run the following:
>   `mysql -u root -p`

After entering the password you just set, you will see the MySQL prompt.

Answer (score 22):

You can simply reset the root password by running the server with --skip-grant-tables and logging in without a password by running the following as root or with sudo:

```
service mysql stop
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
mysql -u root

mysql> use mysql;
mysql> update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("YOUR-NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD") where User='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit

# service mysql stop
# service mysql start
$ mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: After doing this I got an error saying "Plugin 'unix_socket' is not loaded". Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37879449/2934081 (add `update user set plugin="mysql_native_password"; ` after the `update user` line).

Comment: This should be correct answer as previous are depreciated

Answer (score 22):

Edit:

You can login with user `debian-sys-maint`, which has all the expected privileges, the password is in the file `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`

---

Original answer:

As of **Ubuntu 20.04 with MySql 8.0** : the function `PASSWORD` do not exists any more, hence the right way is:

1. login to mysql with `sudo mysql -u root`
2. change the password:

> ```
> USE mysql;
> UPDATE user set authentication_string=NULL where User='root';
> FLUSH privileges;
> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'My-N7w_And.5ecure-P@s5w0rd';
> FLUSH privileges;
> QUIT
> ```

now you should be able to login with `mysql -u root -p` (or to phpMyAdmin with username root) and your chosen password.

Answer (score 12):

The only option that worked for me is the one described in [this link](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04/).

In summary (in case the website goes down), it says:

> To install MySQL:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

> On the next prompt, you will be asked to set a password for the MySQL root user.  Once you do that the script will also ask you to remove the anonymous user, restrict root user access to the local machine and remove the test database. You should answer “Y” (yes) to all questions.

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

> Then

```
sudo mysql

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'very_strong_password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

After that you can exit:

```
exit
```

Now you can easily login with (Remember to type your **very_strong_password**):

```
mysql -u root -p
# type the password now.
```

This was the only option that worked for me after many hours trying the options above.

Answer (score 9):

- Use `sudo mysql -u root -p`, it lets you in with any password if not then use `sudo mysql`.
- If you're entering the console successfully then do the following.

Drop the root user.

```
DROP USER 'root'@'localhost';
```

Create it again.

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Grant the permission.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Restart mysql service.

```
service mysql restart
```

---

If you still can't enter the console, you have to re-install the mysql.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common -y

sudo apt-get autoremove -y

sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
```

Delete all MySQL files on your server:

```
sudo find / -iname 'mysql*' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Install mysql.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Do the installation.

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

- I did the same when I had this problem, hope it helps!

Answer (score 7):

In latest version, mySQL uses `auth_socket`, so to login you've to know about the auto generated user credentials. or if you download binary version, while installation process, you can choose `lagacy password`.

To install SQL in linux debian versions

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

to know about the password

```
sudo cat /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

Now login

```
mysql -u debian-sys-maint -p
```

use the password from `debian.cnf`

How to see available user records:

```
USE mysql
SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user;
```

Now you can create a new user. Use the below commands:

```
use mysql;
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
flush privileges;
```

To list the grants for the particular mysql user

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'username'@'localhost';
```

How to revoke all the grants for the particular mysql user

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION FROM 'username'@'localhost';
```

To delete/remove particular user from user account list

```
DROP USER 'username'@'localhost';
```

For more commands:

```
$ man 1 mysql
```

Please don't reset the password for root, instead create a new user and grant rights. This is the best practice.

Answer (score 6):

**As of Ubuntu 20.04**, using the default MariaDB 10.3 package, these were the necessary steps (remix of earlier answers from this thread):

1. Log in to mysql as root: `sudo mysql -u root`
2. Update the password:

```sql
USE mysql;
UPDATE user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("YOUR-NEW-ROOT-PASSWORD") where User='root';
UPDATE user set plugin="mysql_native_password" where User='root';
FLUSH privileges;
QUIT
```

3. `sudo service mysql restart`

After this, you can connect to your local mysql with your new password: `mysql -u root -p`

Answer (score 5):

1. the first you should stop mysql
2. use this command `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &`
3. and then input `mysql -u root`
   try this way,I have been solved my problem with this method.

Comment: Didn't work. I had to create /var/run/mysqld, but I eventually got another error. mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended. syslog said: Could not create unix socket lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.lock. Had to chown mysql:mysql to /var/run/mysqld folder then it worked!

Comment: Im getting error as mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists on second point

Answer (score 2):

I think another place to look is `/var/lib`. 
If you go there you can see three mysql folders with 'interesting' permissions:

```
user   group 
mysql  mysql
```

Here is what I did to solve my problem with root password:

after running

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql
```

I also ran the following (instead of my_username put yours):

```
cd /var/lib
sudo chown --from=mysql <my_username> mysql* -R
sudo rm -rf mysql*
```

And then:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

which prompted me to select a new root password.
I hope it helps

Comment: Removing /etc/mysql prevents mysql-server from being reinstalled in 19.04

Comment: What you said about 19.04 doesn't make sense. I think you are doing something wrong besides the steps described above. Also, FYI: "Ubuntu 19.04 will be released on 18th April 2019" and today is April 5, 2019

Comment: Also, the question says "Default password of mysql in ubuntu server 16.04" I don't see 19.04 there

Comment: Should have said 19.04 beta. You are right, this probably does not apply to 16.04. In 19.04 beta, (re)installing mysql-server does not prompt for the root password. And I did purge mysql-server*, not mysql* (which would cause too many packages to be uninstalled), and the /etc/mysql directory is created by mysql-common, so removing it by hand without removing that package prevents mysql-server from installing.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 with mysql 8, the weird hashing thing is because the native PASSWORD() function was removed in mysql 8 (or earlier?)

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET 
 plugin = 'mysql_native_password',
 Host = '%',
 authentication_string = CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('insert password here'))))) 
WHERE User = 'root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Following gave me cred for freshly installed mysql

```
sudo cat /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

I tried connceting with workbench and it worked out for me following is to install workbench

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7`

You can find the version you have installed by running `dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql-server`

Comment: This command did not give the option to set the root password

Answer (score 0):

Early versions allowed root password to be blank but, in Newer versions set the root password is the admin(main) user login password during the installation.

Answer (score 0):

If you install your mysql with `apt install mysql`.
you can just login to your mysql with `sudo mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

For new installation, mysql password for `root` is generated and written to the logs `/var/log/mysqld.log`.
If you're trying to automate mysql solution, you can use password from variable:

`mysql_pass=$(sudo grep -oP "temporary password is generated for root@localhost: \K(.*)" /var/log/mysqld.log)`

`mysql -uroot -p"$mysql_pass" < somescript.sql`

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL 8.0.15 (maybe earlier than this too): the PASSWORD() function does not work anymore, so you have to do:

Make sure you have stopped MySQL first (Go to: 'System Preferences' >> 'MySQL' and stop MySQL).

Run the server in safe mode with privilege bypass:

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
mysql -u root
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=null WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit;
```

Then

```
mysql -u root
ALTER USER 'root'@'lo`enter code here`calhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 
'yourpasswd';
```

Finally, start your MySQL again.