# Why does the installer for mysql not ask me to setup a password on Ubuntu 16?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

For some reason, when I try to install MariaDB or MySQL on Ubuntu 16 desktop using package management at a terminal, there is no part of the installation that asks for a password.  It just finishes with indications that all was successful.  Then I am unable to get into the database because I have no idea what the password is.  It is very strange.  If I did a fresh install and selected a LAMP stack it would ask me for the password when installing mysql.
    My solution seems to be to add MariaDB using something like Bitnami or Docker.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default password of mysql in ubuntu server 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421585/default-password-of-mysql-in-ubuntu-server-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Default password of mysql in ubuntu server 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421585/default-password-of-mysql-in-ubuntu-server-16-04/46124188#46124188)

Basically, the problem is that, I guess, mysql-server creates folders in /var/lib that cannot be 'purged' using apt-get. 
Removing those folders and reinstalling mysql-server solved my problem. Just don't forget to change the ownership of /var/lib/mysql* folders to your username.
I hope it helps