# Cant connect to mysql db by workbench but can log in via terminal

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

Im trying to connect to a mysql database crated on my local, however when I try to log in on mysql-workbench I get the following error:

```
  Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

My password is the standard `password`, and my user is `root`.. What I find even stranger is that if I try and log in too the db using `mysql -u root -p` and then proceed to enter the password `password` I log in fine no issue? Has anything experienced this before?

I have double checked everything, mysql workbench even recognizes a databse is active on my localhost on the initial interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to reset the root passwd from here :
 https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/

or follow this : 
[How to change the mysql root password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789522/how-to-change-the-mysql-root-password)

Comment: This surely can't be the issue though as I have the correct password and user for logging in via terminal

Comment: i had the same issue in the past i used to reset the password , or reinstall & purge your mysql server from begin . Sometimes mariadb & mysql-common made issues toghter on while same machine . hope this help u out

Answer (score 0):

May I also add that I was stupidly using my mysql password where I was meant to use my system password, wasted many hours due to this.